# Seeing "This is not an active repository" for an active repository

Tags: travis-ci

I recently received this message:

```
This is not an active repository
```

[image]

for a repository that is active and has a long build history; the [link from a build at github](https://travis-ci.org/pyspeckit/pyspeckit/builds/75710658) brought me to this.  What might cause this to happen to a previously healthy repository?

Comment: Can confirm. I see exactly the same issue with my repo (which already had about 200 builds): https://travis-ci.org/sangria-graphql/sangria Have no idea why it happens though.

Comment: I solved it by "activating" my repo on travis after logging in, but this behavior is new today.  I'll wait and see if anyone has a better answer

Comment: Thanks! This solved the issue for me as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `roidrage` (a Travis-CI member):

> If this repository is indeed still active, then it's likely it was enabled via manual configuration of the GitHub webhook in the GitHub settings for the repositories instead of enabling the hook on the Travis CI account.
>
> This is easy to fix, you just need to go to your profile and activate it manually. That should make the message disappear.

More info [here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5629)